# fetch data based on category django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am creating a stock photography portal so i have the main page where all the image category are listed what i want that when i click on any category then it should fetch data based on category
view.py:

```
def imageview(request):
    #cat_image = request.GET.get()
    allimage = image.objects.all()

    cat= category.objects.all()
    context = {'allimage': allimage, 'cat': cat}
    return render(request, 'image/search.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
class category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True, 
             related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('slug', 'parent') 
    verbose_name_plural = "categories"

def __str__(self):  
    full_path = [self.name]
    k = self.parent
    while k is not None:
        full_path.append(k.name)
        k = k.parent
    return ' -> '.join(full_path[::-1])

class image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'home/tboss/Desktop/image') 
    default = 'home/tboss/Desktop/image/logo.png')
    category = models.ForeignKey('category', null=True, blank=True, 
               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('search/', views.imageview, name= 'imageview')
]
```

also i'm trying to include category based search. I don't know what will be the best way to do this

Comment: If you've done [the official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/), you should be able to find the solution from the examples given. Else, well, you should probably do the tutorial first ;-)

Comment: As a side note: you may also want to follow conventions and capitalize your class names.

Comment: okay every time i make some change in class name or any field i have to delete all the table in database. does it necessary?or is there any other way?

Comment: Django has database migrations and you'd better learn to use them (seriously: [do the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models), it will save you a LOT of time and frustrations). But just changing the capitalization of the models names should not affect the database schema since the table names are (by default) built from a lower-cased version of the models names. And it's better to fix such issues as soon as possible, before you have a production database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to get the single category object first and then you can get all the images of this category like this:

```
def category_images(request,pk):

    category = get_object_or_404(Category,pk=pk)
    images_in_that_category = category.image_set.all()
    return render(request,'template',{'images':images}
```

OR you can filter like this:

```
    images_in_that_category = Image.objects.filter(category=category)
```